# How to change a HTML element's value from node.js

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

I have a Contact form and when i click submit button it's redirects localhost:3000/submits and i save user's datas to MySQL that's okay but i don't know how to change HTML element's values(like paragraph ,headers).. codes in below

i want to change the html element's on the submit page(or i want to create a function that creates submit object )

i thought that

```
<script>
var para=document.createElement('p')
function createNewSubmit(name,email,topic){

document.textContent='"+name+"';

}

</script>
```

I thought using this function but i don't know how to call this function from node.js please help me

This is submit page:

```
        <div class="contact">      
            <h2 class="name" id="name">Name</a></h2>
            <h2 class="email" id="email">Trial@xxx.com</h2>
            
            <div class="message" id="topic">message</div>
            <div class="date" id="date"></div>
            

    </div>
```

This is Contact page that redirects you to /submits

```
        <form action="http://localhost:3000/submits" method="POST">
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="your Name..">
      
          <label for="email">E-mail</label>
          <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="your E-mail..">

          <label for="topic">Topic</label>
          <textarea name="topic" id="topic" placeholder="Write something.."></textarea>

          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
      </div>
```

This is node.js code :

```
app.get('/submits',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/submitPage.html')
    

    var con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "localhost",
      user: "root",
      password: "",
      database: "unityrehberim",
      port:"3306"
    });
    con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var sql = "SELECT * FROM unityrehberim.submits WHERE isim;";
      
      



      con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        
        if (err) throw err;
        result.forEach(element=>{
          console.log(element);
        });
        console.log(result.affectedRows + " record(s) updated");
      });
    });
      



    })
```

all required libraries added for that code

Comment: Tip: It's 2021. You're allowed to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead of all this concatenation.

Comment: Tip: SQL statements don't need the `;` delimiter when run programmatically like this. That's only necessary in interactive shells or in prepared statements. It's also a bad plan to connect every single time you receive a request. Use connection pooling!

Comment: Tip: Consider using a Promise-driven database layer like [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/) so you can `await` your results. Writing callback-style code turns into a complete mess really quickly.

Comment: Your form uses a method of `POST` to `/submits` but your code only includes an example of how the `GET` method is handled. If you want to leverage dynamic content from node in the frontend of your app, you must provide it in the response. What application framework are you using - if it's `Express` then what view engine are you using?